# How to resize a DataFrame dropping columns where NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build a function to recize an existing dataframe into 1 row data frame.

The function looks like below :

```
def RecizeDF(DataFrame,RowNum):
    NewDF = DataFrame.loc[[RowNum]]
    NewDF = NewDF.reset_index()
    NewDF = NewDF.dropna(how='all',axis=0)
    return NewDF
```

But when I print :

```
print(RecizeDF(DF,2))
```

it does return :

```
   Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  ...  Unnamed: 1266  Unnamed: 1267
0  20170428.0  20170531.0  ...            NaN            NaN
```

So we can see that column with NaN Values aren't removed.

How would you remove columns where values are NaN ?

I tried to add `inplace = True` but there it does return `None`

The output would be the following :

```
   Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  ...  
0  20170428.0  20170531.0  ...
```

Comment: Do you want to drop the rows or columns with missing values?

Comment: There is only one row so I want to delete the `columns` where row data = NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the axis in your dropna.

axis=0 is index axis, then you request the whole row to be None to be removed.

axis=1 is columns axis, it shall fit your desired behaviour.